# pointer to array and two dimensional array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
struct packet_event *packet_event_p[8];
```

What does this mean ? Is it a pointer to an array of structure data type (struct packet_event) that has 8 elements ? And how could I make use of this pointer ? 

Is it different from :

```
struct packet_event **packet_event_p;
```

If yes, how could I use this pointer ?

Comment: declare packet_event_p as array 8 of pointer to struct packet_event

Comment: Second one is: declare packet_event_p as pointer to pointer to struct packet_event

Comment: Add [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) to your favorites bar. Seriously. Do it. [First snippet](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=struct+packet_event+*packet_event_p%5B8%5D%3B), [second snippet](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=struct+packet_event+**packet_event_p%3B).

Comment: @WhozCraig That'a not a bad idea, do you think it's important to know these complicated declerations ?

Comment: @BohaoLI You career using C will be woefully cut short unless you can readily understand declarations like this pretty much on-sight.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, that's true, and not understanding the declarations just make me crazy. I will look at cdecl.org :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one:

```
struct packet_event *packet_event_p[8];
```

stands for 'declare packet_event_p as an array of 8 pointers to struct packet_event'.  Thus, you create an array `packet_event_p` of 8 elements, which are pointers to the struct packet_event.  Please see [this link](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=struct+packet_event+*packet_event_p%5B8%5D%3B).

whereas the second one:

```
struct packet_event **packet_event_p;
```

stands for 'declare packet_event_p as pointer to pointer to struct packet_event'.  Please see [this link](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=struct+packet_event+**packet_event_p%3B).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: So that the first pointer is a pointer to an array who has 8 elements ?

Comment: @BohaoLI, first is not actually a pointer per se.  It is an *array of pointers*.

Comment: Bohao Li, think of it this way `struct packaet_event *foo[x]` creates an *array of pointers* (8 pointers), that you are free to use as you would any pointer and you can address them in array notation (e.g. `foo[1], foo[2]` and so on . `struct packet_event **packet_event_p;` creates a *pointer-to-pointer-to-type struct packet*. It is nothing more than 1 of them. However, you can allocate as many as you need, and `realloc` if you need more later. Each pointer you allocate here is a pointer to a newly allocated block of memory of type ans size `struct packet_event`. Let me know if you have q's.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks. Another question : for the second pointer `struct packet_event **packet_event_p`, am I able to use it like using the first pointer ? Like `packent_event_p[5] = ...`. And the difference between the two pointers is that : the first pointer has a size while the second doesn't. Is that ritght ?

Comment: @BatCoder How do you translate "an array 8 of pointers", I don't really get it.... Is it the same thing as "an array of 8 pointers" .....

Comment: @BohaoLI, yes, edited the answer.  Sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: @BohaoLI, yes, but you must allocate the pointers. In `packent_event_p[5]` you take advantage of the auto-allocation provided for statically allocated objects. With`struct packet_event **packet_event_p`, if you want the same `5` pointers, then you must do `packet_event_p = malloc (sizeof *packet_event_p * 5);` NOW you have `**event_pack_p` in the same state of readiness to accept address for each of the pointers as you do with, e.g. `packent_event_p[5]` that was statically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The first declaration :

```
struct packet_event *packet_event_p[8];
```

defines an ***array*** of `8` elements, each element of which is a pointer to `struct packet_event` . In other words, you have an array of `8` pointers, and each one points to a `struct packet_event`.

> And how could I make use of this pointer ?

You can allocate memory for a `struct packet_event` and set a pointer of your array point to it, like this :

```
struct packet_event *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct packet_event));
if (ptr == NULL)
    printf ("Error\n");
else
    packet_event_p[0] = ptr;    //choose a pointer packet_event_p[0] - packet_event_p[7]
```

---

The second declaration :

```
struct packet_event **packet_event_p;
```

is different, as you declare a ***pointer*** (and *not an array*), named `packet_event_p`, which points to a pointer to `struct packet_event`.

> If yes, how could I use this pointer ?

Allocate memory for the *double pointer* `packet_event_p`. See [this link](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/) for allocating memory for double pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that arrays can be decayed to pointers, but they are not the same.

regarding the type it is "Array of 8 pointers to a struct of packed event"
reading the types in C usually goes in some sort of a whirlwind fashion. To properly to do, you can read this [here](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html).

Usually when you are passing this type as function argument, you will also add the size of the array, or use an external known variable to mark its length. Usually function declarations will be pointers instead of arrays type. I think even that the compiler does automatically (comments about that will be useful)

One different between those types can be seen using the `sizeof` operator. when applied on variable which is known to be an array type, then the result is the entire size of the array. Otherwise it will be a size of a pointer, which might be 4 byte or 8 byte (depending if its a 64/32bit machine).